# Locale identifier for maori language not supported

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to use apple's `SFSpeechRecognizer` with maori language. I want to detect/classify best string spoken and then match with Maori string name, I will get from API.

Lets say I have an image with Marvel hero Hulk, with it's Maori locale version **"Tuhinga o mua"**. Now if user speakes the same string it is a pass otherwise it is fail.

**What I hav tried:**

```
print(SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales())
```

This outputs:

```
[es-419 (fixed), th-TH (fixed), ca-ES (fixed), fr-BE (fixed), de-CH (fixed), sk-SK (fixed), en-ZA (fixed), es-CL (fixed), hi-IN (fixed), zh-CN (fixed), zh-TW (fixed), da-DK (fixed), hi-IN-translit (fixed), el-GR (fixed), he-IL (fixed), pt-BR (fixed), en-AE (fixed), pt-PT (fixed), fr-CH (fixed), ro-RO (fixed), vi-VN (fixed), en-SA (fixed), pl-PL (fixed), es-US (fixed), hi-Latn (fixed), en-SG (fixed), tr-TR (fixed), hr-HR (fixed), ko-KR (fixed), uk-UA (fixed), it-CH (fixed), ar-SA (fixed), id-ID (fixed), en-IN (fixed), es-ES (fixed), de-AT (fixed), en-IE (fixed), cs-CZ (fixed), es-CO (fixed), zh-HK (fixed), sv-SE (fixed), en-PH (fixed), en-ID (fixed), en-CA (fixed), nl-NL (fixed), yue-CN (fixed), en-NZ (fixed), en-GB (fixed), ja-JP (fixed), it-IT (fixed), ru-RU (fixed), en-US (fixed), ms-MY (fixed), es-MX (fixed), hu-HU (fixed), fr-CA (fixed), wuu-CN (fixed), de-DE (fixed), fr-FR (fixed), fi-FI (fixed), nb-NO (fixed), nl-BE (fixed), en-AU (fixed)]
```

The above output does not specify locale for maori language.

Can we us `SFSpeechRecognizer` with Maori language?
Can we get all the words from audio stream? Then create a array of words and just math a word with Maori string?

Please provide me the right direction.

Comment: Seeing as the Maori language is not included in the list of supported locales I'm not sure what answer you expect form this other than no?

Comment: No, it does not, is this requirement technically feasible without using private API. Any experience or two words? Thanks

Comment: Using SFSpeechRecognizer the only possibility is to use one of the supported locales. If you want to use speech to text for Maori you would have to look into using a third party speech recogniser that supports Maori.

Comment: I see, thaks for your time :)